# Visualizing Push Forward

Tags: differential-geometry

$\newcommand{R}{\mathbb R}$
I am studying O'Neil's Elementary Differential geometry and find that the push forward is defined as :

> Let $F=(f_1,f_2,\ldots, f_m):\R^n\to\R^m$ be differentiable and $\boldsymbol{v}\in T_p\R^n$ then the tangent map or push-forward at $p$ is
> $$F_*:T_p\R^n\to T_{F(p)}\R^m,\boldsymbol{v}\mapsto (\boldsymbol{v}[f_1],\ldots,\boldsymbol{v}[f_m])$$

I would like to ask if there is any visualization of this for better understanding.

Comment: Well, the word visualizing is a bit unclear to me. Maybe https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pushforward_(differential) would be helpful.

Answer (score 3):

Let $v$ be a tangent vector at $p$. Take a curve $\gamma$ defined in some neighborhood of $0$, satisfying

$\gamma(0) = p$

and

$\gamma'(0) = v$

that is, a curve that goes through $p$ with velocity $v$ (for example, the straight line $\gamma(t) = p + tv$). Then $F$ maps this curve to another curve $\mu(t) = F(\gamma(t))$ such that $\mu(0) = F(p)$.

The pushforward $F_*(v)$ of $v$ is precisely the velocity vector of this new curve:

$F_*(v) = \mu'(0) = (F\circ\gamma)'(0)$.

One can show that this vector depends linearly on $v$ (this is equivalent to the differentiability of $F$) and doesn't depend on the curve $\gamma$ chosen.

This means that $F$ maps curves passing through $p$ to curves passing through $F(p)$, and the pushforward at $p$ is the linear map which transforms the velocities (tangent vectors at $p$) of these curves.

This interpretation is discussed in that same book. See the section about mappings (page 38, Theorem 7.8 in the edition I'm consulting).

Edit: I found a picture which illustrates this very well. Here, $\phi$ is the smooth map and $T_p\phi$ denotes its pushforward:

[image]

$M$ and $N$ are the domain and codomain of the smooth map. The red squares illustrate the pullback of differential forms, something you will also find in that book.